# XSL rename element name but namespace in the wrong place

Tags: xslt, maximo

I have an xml and i want to rename/changes the element name and leave everthing unchanges but i facing the unexpected result.

Incoming XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublishVENDOR baseLanguage="EN" messageID="507085.1468382418796837538" event="1" xmlns="http://store/companies" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <VENDORSet>
    <COMPANIES action="Replace">
      <ADDRESS1>32 SUMNER STREET</ADDRESS1>
      <ADDRESS2>HARTFORD</ADDRESS2>
      <ADDRESS3>CT</ADDRESS3>
      <ADDRESS4>03342</ADDRESS4>
    </COMPANIES>
  </VENDORSet>
</PublishVENDOR>
```

XSL Map

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="http://store/companies" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/ns:PublishVENDOR">
    <xsl:element name="SyncVENDOR">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SyncMXVENDOR baseLanguage="EN" messageID="507085.1468382418796837538" event="1">
  <VENDORSet xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <COMPANIES action="Replace">
      <ADDRESS1>32 SUMNER STREET</ADDRESS1>
      <ADDRESS2>HARTFORD</ADDRESS2>
      <ADDRESS3>CT</ADDRESS3>
      <ADDRESS4>03342</ADDRESS4>
    </COMPANIES>
  </VENDORSet>
</SyncVENDOR>
```

The result that i want is

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SyncVENDOR baseLanguage="EN" messageID="507085.1468382418796837538" event="1" xmlns="http://store/companies" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <VENDORSet>
    <COMPANIES action="Replace">
      <ADDRESS1>32 SUMNER STREET</ADDRESS1>
      <ADDRESS2>HARTFORD</ADDRESS2>
      <ADDRESS3>CT</ADDRESS3>
      <ADDRESS4>03342</ADDRESS4>
    </COMPANIES>
  </VENDORSet>
</SyncVENDOR>
```

Please somebody help me... and i'm sorry that my english is not good too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:template match="/ns:PublishVENDOR">
    <xsl:element name="SyncVENDOR">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="/ns:PublishVENDOR">
    <SyncVENDOR xmlns="http://store/companies">
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </SyncVENDOR>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: hi martin... thanks your answer is working... but why the xmlns:ns="http://store/companies" show at SyncVENDOR element on xml output